# Banning clients from a node server

Tags: xml, node.js, filesystems, ip, blacklist

I'm trying to get a IP-ban functionality into my server.
as I've found no suiting module, i try to write my own.

Now I'm thinking about what is the best way to implement the following:

being able to ban a certain IP for a certain amount of time.

right now (i have just started), i have:

an XML with

```
<root>
    <entry IP="123.123.123.123">
        <time>13.09.2015</time>
    </entry>
</root>
```

and the corresponding checker function

```
module.exports.checkBan = function(ip) {

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/ban.xml', function(err, data) {
    var banned = false;
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            var length = result['root']['entry'].length;

            for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
                if (ip == result['root']['entry'][i]['$']['IP']) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
};
```

however, problems arise:

the checkBan function does not have a boolean value, as it is asynchroneous.
that means, every(!) request will have to wait until the function returns, before it can be processed (or not, if the client is banned).
that will generate a lot of unneccessary waiting overhead...i think?
if i implement a promise, requests will be served, even if they are banned, i assume.
and btw: those returns don't work, as i've noticed :(

how is this done in "big" sites?
how is it done RIGHT?

i want to minimize access times to the ip-blacklist, and minimize access overhead in general for every request, while still being able to check if an ip is banned.
how can i achieve this?

thanks

Comment: larger sites would use something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on the webserver and filter request before they even hit your application.  I know nginx you can define a file of IP address you want to block and add it to a config. 

What web framework are you using for your node application, if any?

Comment: i'm using just express. would i be able to use e.g. fail2ban with a node server? i guess that will require further reading.. what would be the easiest way to do it? thanks :)

Comment: There is probably a way but I have no experience doing so. And if you were worried about this is a production environment you probably wouldn't just be running node by itself. if should be behind some kind of webserver like apache or nginx

Comment: well i was planning to release just the node server. but you're right, this actually is my first node project, so i'm fairly new to the whole system. so you say i'd have an apache running that handles requests and forwards them to my node? do you have a couple of hints that i can google to better understand the whole procedure?

Comment: My experience is with nginx. google nginx node reverse proxy.  Same applies for the Apache though. its called reverse proxying

Comment: thanks! i've now got an nginx running and configured as reverse proxy. until now, everything is working. now how would i be able to insert/delete entries in the blockips.conf from my node app? my first idea would be an ajax call to an nginx script , but is there an easier/better way? thanks for your help :)

Comment: You wouldn't. You would just manually type them in your config file and that would achieve your goal of blocking IPs from accessing your application. If you're trying to make some kind of interactive IP blocker application within your node app then I feel thats outside the scope of this question.

Comment: google seems to know NOTHING about editing a list of blocked ips (via nginx or iptables) on a running server... or am i just blind?

Comment: there must be a way to block IPs while the site is running?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that should really be implemented at the machine level or web server. I would think the easiest step would be to start by using iptables on your server to block particular IP's from accessing your machine. Large sites will use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or similar to block ranges of IPs or monitor for malicious traffic.

Both nginx and apache have modules built in that allow you the ability to allow and deny certain IP addresses using configuration in the web server it self to block traffic.

if you were really hellbent on implementing this yourself I wouldn't constantly read from a file. I would load the IPs into memory if small enough, or something like redis if it got too large for memory, or even a database. Depending on your web framework for node, if you are using one, if it supports middlewares I would then implement the logic to check the list of IPs as part of a middle ware that would execute before it hit any of your applications routes.